# What is the password for jenkins user under MACOSX?

Tags: macos, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to create a CI for iOS (iPhone and iPad) using TestFlight, Jenkings, GitHub, Sonar...
I downloaded the macosx jenkings package/wizard. It seems it created a user for my mac.
What is its password?
Because I'm having problems with the keychain and I guess it is because I'm user my own user instead of jenkins profile.
Kind Regards,
Ricardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it's not set by default (empty).

Read this article (how to change password in OS X from command line):
http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/19/change-password-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-without-knowing-current-password/

Answer (score 27):

I always use `sudo su jenkins -` to work as the Jenkins user on the command line, this should also work on a Mac. Then you don't need the password at all.

I don't have my MacBook with me to tests this now, but on my current linux server the jenkins user was created with shell /bin/false. I changed the shell in /etc/passwd to /bin/bash, after that I could login with `su` as the Jenkins user to setup ssh-keys, etc...

Comment: Niels' "sudo su jenkins" is exactly the same solution I just came up with independently, and it does work on a Mac.

Comment: @Niels `sudo su jenkins -` login jenkins is ok,but Permission denied when do anything

Comment: Would expect the same with a regular password login, guess you need to check the permissions.

Answer (score 11):

No password is set by default for user `jenkins`. You need to set it up by executing `sudo passwd jenkins`

Comment: how do i know the user it is using? is there any command to check for the user name. I have installed jenkins for the first time and unable to login. Can someone pls help

Comment: @Ashvitha Did you get the answer

Answer (score 4):

```
cat /Users/[username]/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the initial password here /Users/{username}/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

Answer (score 0):

A Default password location is changed in the latest version of Jenkins.

```
sudo cat /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```