# why jenkins create a new user named 'Jenkins' when install jenkins on osx and i don't know the password

Tags: macos, jenkins

install jenkins in mackbook pro and success.

but I don't know why jenkins create a new user named 'Jenkins',

and I don't know this user's password,

how to get this password and can I delete this user??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the password for jenkins user under MACOSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800948/what-is-the-password-for-jenkins-user-under-macosx)

Comment: @Thilo it's asked 3 year ago,and my osx is `Capitan` not `Lion`

Comment: @Thilo       No password is set by default for user jenkins. You need to set it up by executing `sudo passwd jenkins` , and I had delete this user, thank you!but I don't know why create this user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X software frequently creates special users to do specific tasks.  By running as its own user, it prevents that software from accessing or modifying your own private files inadvertently, and also prevents users from accidentally modifying that software's private data files.

Note that those sorts of user accounts usually are *not* login users—that is, they typically do not have a password, because you can't log in as that user.  Instead, the software starts out running as the root user (superuser) and then reduces its privileges to those of the non-login user account.

Comment: so I can delete this user?

Comment: Only if you aren't using Jenkins anymore.